# Installing php5-fpm but missing www.conf

Tags: php

I am installing php5-fpm on my ubuntu system but could not able to find **www.conf** file under pool.d directory.

In my /etc/php5/fpm folder, there are only 2 directories - **conf.d** and **pool.d**

Command which I am using -

```
apt-get install php5-fpm
```

Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

www.conf is in pool.d folder

```
 /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

Comment: www.conf is not under pool.d directory. Directory is empty :(

Comment: try purging and reinstalling php5-fpm.

Answer (score 0):

after installing php5-fpm see in pool.d folder, there is a www.conf file

[image: screen shot]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @amc well, saying "but there is such a file, I tell you where to look" is at least an attempt to give an answer.

Comment: Actually I answered in the previous comment. But just to improve where to find the file, I shared the screen shot. He was unable to locate the file. So I just helped him where to find the desired file.